# Python - Separate tuples from the return of another function into different variable

Tags: python

I have a function that return 2 values that are 2 tuples in a couple. Here is the function:

```
def validate_move(self):
    import ast
    source = tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in input("position:").split(','))
    target = tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in input("position:").split(','))
    if self.validate_position_source(source) == True:
        if self.validate_position_target(source, target) == True:
            return source, target
```

A return looks like this:

```
((3, 2), (1, 4))
```

The first tuple being source and the second target.I want to have both tuples into a variable in another function. For example here,

```
a = (3,2)
b= (1,4)
```

I know i have to call the function but i don't know how to "extract" the tuples into the variables.

Comment: Watch out, if one or both of your `if` statements is `False`, this will return `None` and you will get an error when you try to unpack `None` as a `tuple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign to multiple variables:

```
a, b = obj.validate_move()
```

Python will unpack the return value for you and assign each element to the different targets named to the left of the `=` assignment.

You could also just address each element in the tuple:

```
result = obj.validate_move()
a = result[0]
b = result[1]
```

but the unpacking assignment is much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
source, target = your_object.validate_move()
```